# How do I seed the random integer function on Scheme's srfi 27 library?

Tags: scheme, racket, srfi

I am writing a program on Scheme that uses the random integer library from srfi 27.  However, every time I run the program on my laptop or a friend's the function returns the same value.  Looking at the documentation, I am unable to find the correct function to seed the random function.

I have tried calling (make-random-source) but I am not sure how to then set the new source as the source for the random integer function to call from.

Answer (score 0):

The only portable way that I know of is to use

```
(random-source-randomize! default-random-source)
```

before calling `random-integer` or `random-real`. Or if you want a reproducible initial state, `random-source-pseudo-randomize!` instead. There's also `random-source-state-set!`, but what is acceptable for the state is implementation-defined.

If you're creating a new random source instead of using the default, use `random-source-randomize!` on it first before using with `random-source-make-integers` etc.

---

Since you mention Racket, its SRFI-27 implementation uses Racket [pseudo-random generators](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28part._.Random_.Numbers%29) as random sources and `random-source-state-set!` just calls [`vector->pseudo-random-generator!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._vector-%7E3epseudo-random-generator%21%29%29).